# Microsoft Hololens Tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently [asked a question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/69567/is-there-a-hololens-1-compatible-browser-ad-blocker) about a Microsoft Hololens 1.

I don't have enough rep to create tags yet, but I'm wondering if there's value in a [hololens](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hololens) (or a [hololens-1](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hololens-1) and [hololens-2](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hololens-2) with the 2 allegedly coming out "soon").

I do see value in it in that there are definitely Windows Store applications that are Hololens- and PC-specific, so it's technically a different platform than Windows on a desktop or phone.

If it's useful, somebody with the privilege can create it. Otherwise... *shrug*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just created the tag.

Feel free to tag any other question that covers that topic.